# C++ std::async segfault only when using std::launch::async policy

Tags: c++, g++, std

The following code produces a segfault on the function call (valgrind trace follows).

```
GrooveFeat procGroove(double tRadius);
```

...

```
std::future<GrooveFeat> *features = new std::future<GrooveFeat>[evalCount];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < evalCount; i++) {
  double effRadius = evalMin + evalStep*i;
  std::cout << "Allocating feature " << i << "\n";
  features[i] = std::async(std::launch::async, &procGroove, effRadius);
}

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < evalCount; i++) {
  std::cout << "Waiting on evaluation " << i << "/" << evalCount << "\n";
  GrooveFeat feat = features[i].get();

  ...
}
delete[] features;
```

When this code is reached, I see a segfault between the allocation of features 1-5 (the exact feature varies from execution to execution). If evalCount is manually set to 1, the same error persists as soon as the thread is activated.

```
Allocating feature 0
Allocating feature 1
Allocating feature 2
==27135== Thread 2:
==27135== Invalid read of size 8
==27135==    at 0x403B39: procGroove(double) (in profilParr)
==27135==    by 0x40552B: std::_Function_handler<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> (), std::__future_base::_Task_setter<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result<GrooveFeat>, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter>, std::_Bind_simple<GrooveFeat (*(double))(double)>, GrooveFeat> >::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&) (in /profilParr)
==27135==    by 0x405608: std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::_M_do_set(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*) (in profilParr)
==27135==    by 0x4E43DCE: __pthread_once_slow (in /usr/lib/libpthread-2.21.so)
==27135==    by 0x405FEB: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<GrooveFeat (*(double))(double)>, GrooveFeat>::_Async_state_impl(std::_Bind_simple<GrooveFeat (*(double))(double)>&&)::{lambda()#1} ()> >::_M_run() (in profilParr)
==27135==    by 0x510C34F: execute_native_thread_routine (thread.cc:84)
==27135==    by 0x4E3D353: start_thread (in /usr/lib/libpthread-2.21.so)
==27135==    by 0x59D6BFC: clone (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==27135==  Address 0xffffffffffffffc8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Thus, it looks like the segfault is caused by the standard library, since execution ends before any part of procGroove is actually executed.
Compile command is:

```
g++ -O3 -pthread -std=c++11 main.cpp -o profilParr -lpthread
```

On whim, I confirmed that the executable has the same errors regardless of optimization level (ie, with -O0).
Any idea how to go about debugging this? It appears there was a bug report on a similar problem several years ago (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54297), but it is marked as resolved (I'm using v5.1.0).

EDIT: removing the std::launch::async policy specifier allows the program to execute without error. Why???
However, seeing as it defaults to deferred processing, it effectively loses any semblance to executing procGroove() in parallel. Any ways to get around this?

Comment: Why are you taking the address of procGroove?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was barking up the wrong tree.